# Excluir registros com várias condições

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso excluir registros em duplicidade na coluna `bidding_price` com as seguintes condições:

Tabela: `bid_account`

Colunas a serem verificadas:

> `id` = PRIMARY KEY
>  `auction_id` = ID de cada produto
>   `bidding_price` = valor inserido (essa que deve ser verificado a
>   duplicidade para cada produto)
>  `bid_flag` = deve ser sempre igual
>   ao valor de: **'d'**
>  `bidding_type` = deve ser sempre igual ao
>   valor de: **'s'**

Ele sempre vai existir registros iguais na coluna `bidding_price`, o que não pode ter é registros iguais com a mesma ID do produto (`auction_id`).

Exemplo de como não deve ter:

> **auction_id** | **bidding_price**
>   *------10------------0.02
>
>   ------10------------0.02
>
>   ------11------------0.02
>
>   ------11------------0.02*

O correto seria:

> **auction_id** | **bidding_price**
>   *------10------------0.02
>
>   ------11------------0.02*

Eu tentei com o seguinte comando:

```
DELETE ba
    FROM bid_account ba JOIN
         (SELECT ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price, MAX(ba2.id) as max_id
          FROM bid_account ba2
          WHERE ba2.bid_flag = 'd' AND ba2.bidding_type = 's'
          GROUP BY ba2.auction_id, ba2.bidding_price
         ) ba2
         ON ba2.auction_id = ba.auction_id AND
            ba2.bidding_price = ba.bidding_price AND
            ba2.max_id < ba.id
WHERE ba.bid_flag = 'd' AND ba.bidding_type = 's' AND ba.auction_id = ba2.auction_id
```

Só que ele excluiu vários registros, não fez as validações corretamente. Como devo posso fazer?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE ba1 FROM bid_account ba1, bid_account ba2, 
         WHERE ba1.auction_id = ba2.auction_id AND
             ba1.bidding_price = ba2.bidding_price AND
             ba1.max_id < ba2.id AND
                 ba1.bid_flag = 'd' AND 
                 ba1.bidding_type = 's';
```